# Volume By Washers & Midpoint Rule

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

The question I am trying to solve is as follows:

Use the Midpoint Rule with $n = 5$ to estimate the volume obtained by rotating about the $y$-axis the region under the curve $y = \sqrt{1+x^3}$, $0\le x\le1$.

The answer's supposed to be: $3.68$.

I just want to know the exact steps to solve the question; I couldn't get the same answer.

**EDIT:**
Here is how I did it:

- A cross-section from the top would have a hole, so it's a washer.
- The lower y bound is 0 & the upper y bound is sqrt(2).
- Then, I found the y midpoints (midpoint rule).
- The first 3 intervals/slices have r=1, so their combined volume is (3)(pi)sqrt(2)/5.
- The 4th interval/slice has outer r=1 & inner r=7sqrt(2)/5, so its volume is (pi)[sqrt(2)/5]{1-[7sqrt(2)/5]^2}.
- For the 5th interval/slice it has outer r=1 & inner r=9sqrt(2)/5, so its volume is (pi)[sqrt(2)/5]{1-[9sqrt(2)/5]^2}.
- When I calculated it, I got abt. 2.133

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you don't show your work, we can't find the problem.  How did you set it up?  Your washers have a hole in the middle.  Did you account for that?

Comment: I now included the workout under my edit.

Answer (score -1):

Your inner radius should be $r=\sqrt[3]{y^2-1}$ when it is greater than zero.  The five midpoints are at $(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9)\sqrt 2.$  I find only the last has a hole in the middle of radius $\sqrt[3]{(0.9\sqrt 2)^2-1}\approx 0.8527$.

Comment: So I used your radius and got :                                                                                       4(pi)sqrt(2)/5 + (pi)sqrt(2)/5{1-([0.9sqrt(2)]^(2)-1)^(2/3)}                                    - The 1st 4 intervals have r=1                                                                                  - For the 5th interval:                                                                                         
- outer r squared =1 & inner r squared = ([0.9sqrt(2)]^(2)-1)^(2/3)                    - I calculated it and got 3.797, which is closer to 3.68 but not exactly.

Comment: That is what I get.

Comment: Yes, but the (book's) answer is 3.68...

Comment: Books have errors sometimes.  I answered another question yesterday where the book couldn't count to seven.